# Use piece of div-class in css

Tags: html, css

If my div is like this: `<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-street">` is it possible to call it in my css with just a fraction of it? Like `.form-item-field-afl-dienst`

The ending 0 is the number of items on the page, which is not predefined... And I want to catch them all in one css statement..

Or, how can I catch

```
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-street">
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-street">
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-2-street">
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-3-street">
...
```

with one statement?

**EDIT FOR ALEX**

```
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-street">
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-nr">
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-0-zip">

<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-street">
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-nr">
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst-adressen-und-1-zip">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This selector should work.

```
[class^="form-item-field-afl-dienst"]
```

Note older IEs don't support this.

Comment: @Michiel yes it's part of CSS3 see [here](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/) full table - I just now saw it's supported in IE7 and above so as IE6 is long dead by now I would use this.

Comment: Ok, great! You helped me a lot! Thanks alex!

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can have multiple classes:

```
<div class="form-item-field-afl-dienst adressen-und-0-street">
```

Then have:

```
.form-item-field-afl-dienst
{
}

.adressen-und-0-street
{
}
```

Edit: new browsers will support selectors as alex pointed out, but for now if you want it to work with most browsers currently in use, it's not possible.

Comment: @Michiel Changing the class at run time is possible only with JavaScript - you can have script running on page load, replacing the `-0-` with whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to split the class items up:

```
<div class="form-item field-afl 0-street">
```

Then for the combined you can use the CSS:

```
.form-item .field-afl .0-street
{
 ...
}
```

and to use a segment of the class in CSS:

```
.form-item 
{
...
}
```